# Convert large number of pdf to eps

Tags: terminal, zsh

I have a large number of PDF files that I need to convert to EPS. I'm using this command to do that:

```
gs -dNOCACHE -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=eps2write -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile=output.eps input.pdf
```

That converts individual files, but I have a large number of them. How can I convert many pdf files into many eps files, keeping the names before the file extension? I'm using zsh on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a for-loop, but I'd have to rename all the files:

```
for i in *.pdf
do
gs -dNOCACHE -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=eps2write -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile=$i.eps $i
done
```

results in output files having extension `.pdf.eps`, which I then rename with

```
zmv '(*)(.pdf).eps' '$1.eps'
```

Comment: Use `${i:r}.eps` for the output filename. You can find more information about the `r` modifier in the `zshexpn` man page; search for 'root'.